# Difference between Intel-VT and AMD-V

Tags: virtualization, intel, central-processing-unit

What is the difference in hardware between Intel-VT and [AMD-V](http://search.amd.com/ru/_layouts/search/search.aspx?csquery=hardware+virtualization&collection=all-ru)?

I am currently reading [Virtual Machines: Versatile Platforms for Systems and Processes](http://books.google.ie/books?id=LCtNaLNOa4gC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) chapter eight and Intel-VT is mentioned there but I can not find anithing specific about AMD technology.

Answer (score 1):

Either Intel-VT and AMD-V are an implementation of some processor instruction that allow operating system to work well with virtualization.

Basically, i think that, they are the different name of almost the same technology implementation. I don't think that could be a lot of difference between the two ..

Comment: Wikipedia states that they are x86 virtualization but are implemented differently: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization